# Logistic Equation - Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about logistic equations in differential equations and setting up the problem accordingly. This was the question presented:

> The number $N(t)$ of people in a community who are exposed to a particular advertisement is governed by the logistic equation. Initially, $N(0) = 500$, and it is observed that $N(1) = 1000$. Solve for $N(t)$ if it is predicted that the limiting number of people in the community ho will see the advertisement is 50,000

So from the question, we know that the differential equation we are going to solve is
$$\frac{dN}{dt} = N(a-bN)$$

My question is why are logistic equations setup such that
$$\frac{dN}{dt} = kN(50000-N)$$
and not something like
$$\frac{dN}{dt} = N(500-1000N)$$
or something similar?

Perhaps the root of the question is I don't have a clear understanding of what the logistic equation is, but any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advanced for your help!

Comment: because I can look at the first and go the interesting points of the ode at $N=0,5000$ its all scaling factors..so not really of interest as long as you know how/what is scaled..With two factors we could scale everything to $$\frac{d\bar{N}}{dt} = \bar{N}(1-\bar{N})$$ if you wanted to.

Comment: So what you're saying is that a and b are scaling factors?